# Using Zapier to add multiple rows to excel via single slack message

Tags: python, excel, slack, zapier

I am trying to add multiple rows of data into an excel file using zapier from a single slack message. However, I am able to pull only one row at the moment.

Below is the slack message format that I am using. It can have multiple client to description sets which represent each row of data needed in excel file.

```
Client: ABC
Platform (MP/IX/UP): IX
Handover Type (Proactive/Reactive/Tracker): Proactive
Project ID: 1234567
Status (SL/FL/Paused/Waiting): FL
RL: N/A
Description: This is a description text. 
Description text can have multiple paragraphs.


Client: XYZ
Platform (MP/IX/UP): IX
Handover Type (Proactive/Reactive/Tracker): Reactive
Project ID: 12345678
Status (SL/FL/Paused/Waiting): FL
RL: N/A
Description: This is also a description text. 
Description text can have multiple paragraphs.
```

There is also a caveat that the description text may also have multiple lines or paragraphs, which means it can have new line characters.

I tried using code by zapier to run the following python script to format the message, but the issue is it pulls only 1 row of data to excel.

```
# Get the message from the input data
message = input_data["Message"]

# Split the message into lines
lines = message.split("\n")

# Initialize an empty dictionary to store the data
data = {}

# Loop through each line in the lines list
for line in lines:
    # Ignore blank lines
    if line.strip() == "":
        continue

    # Split the line into key and value at the first occurrence of ":"
    key, value = line.split(":", 1)
    # Strip any leading or trailing spaces from the key and value
    key = key.strip()
    value = value.strip()

    # Check if the key is "Description"
    if key == "Description":
        # If the key is "Description", check if there is already a value
        if "Description" in data:
            # If there is already a value, append the current line to the existing value
            data["Description"] += "\n" + value
        else:
            # If there is no existing value, set the current line as the value
            data["Description"] = value
    else:
        # Add the key-value pair to the data dictionary
        data[key] = value

# Initialize an empty list to store the output
output = []

# Append the data dictionary to the output list
output.append(data)
```

If anyone can help me in directing me to how can we achieve this. Please note I am not into coding, though I know a little bit of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly appending `data` into `output` list. Your code structure should go something like this:

```
output = [] # initialize output at the top
for line in lines:
    # code remains the same here
    output.append(data) # this needs to happen within the loop
```

This way you'll append data to output in each iteration thereby getting data for each data point.

Comment: Thanks Usman for your suggestion. Unfortunately this just repeats the same line rather than parse data for each data point.

Comment: It might help to print data at different places in the loop and see where it is missing the items.